# Install RSAT using powershell script to windows 10 with elevated privileges

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

I am facing a difficulty on installing RSAT to remote windows 10 workstations via gpo. My main goal is to use `Get-ADuser` command as a necessity to gain information from my Windows domain.

I created a PowerShell script using the following command:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT* -Online | Add-WindowsCapability –Online
```

Yet when I run it, a message appears asking for elevated privileges.

So I tried to add credentials in order to automate the installation and changed the script to :

```
$Username = 'domain\domain_adm'
$Password = '*******'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList{Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT* -Online | Add-WindowsCapability –Online} -credential $Cred
```

And from a normal PowerShell window, it works. But, it doesn't when I am trying to use it from gpo.

Could you please assist me?

The goal is to install via GPO `Get-ADuser` (maybe RSAT) to domain workstations with OS Windows 10

Comment: This was a gpo login script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why are you putting credentials in clear text in a script file? That
   is just bad practice and should not be done.
2. Installing software is an Admin level thing, local, GPO, or
   otherwise, because it's a system-wide change.

Lastly, this is not a PowerShell code/programming issue and not something PowerShell can fix relative to how you are trying to do this. It's specifically how do I use GPO to enable a Windows feature or install software, using PowerShell?

So, could be considered off-topic for Stackoverflow and more a question for SuperUser or StackExchange.

All that being said, you can still use PowerShell to do this, but doing so by using PowerShell to set a scheduled task to the targets and set that to the admin creds at run once at login.

- You can write a separate script to create the scheduled task.
- You can use the below script for the RSAT install effort via the task.

[Use PowerShell to Create Scheduled Tasks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks)

[New-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps)

Very similar to this approach with updating PowerShell help:

[PowerShell: Update-Help via Scheduled Task in Group Policy Preferences](https://trevorsullivan.net/2013/04/04/powershell-update-help-via-scheduled-task-in-group-policy-preferences)

As far as what js2010 has stated. That was true for earlier versions of Windows 10. The current state of things is as noted below.

> [Install RSAT for Windows 10 1809 and 1903 and 1909 automated](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Install-RSAT-for-Windows-75f5f92f)
>
> ***RSAT*** (Remote Server Administration Tools) in Windows 10 v1809 and
>   v1903 are ***no longer a downloadable add-on to Windows.*** Instead, its
>   included as a set of "Features on Demand" directly in Windows.
>
> Download:  [Install-RSATv1809v1903v1909.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Install-RSAT-for-Windows-75f5f92f/file/225312/1/Install-RSATv1809v1903v1909.ps1)

Long term Scheduled Task management can be accomplished via GPO as well, as noted here:

[Managing Scheduled Tasks from Group Policy](http://www.mdmarra.com/2014/04/managing-scheduled-tasks-from-group.html)

Answer (score 1):

For a small number of machines Powershell is not a bad option.  If you have access to GPOs then you should use then.  RSAT is "Windows feature".  You can use WSUS. https://4sysops.com/archives/install-rsat-1809-and-other-optional-features-in-wsus-environments/  You could also use the software that you use to install software on the machine on the network . Many of software distribution packages run as root when it installs software. In this case just give that team the line below.

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT* -Online | Add-WindowsCapability –Online
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download RSAT as an msu file:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

EDIT:  Ok, as for 1809 and above, my first thoughts are a gpo startup script, or using invoke-command.